# Proper way to handle Query Cursor in Google Firestore? (Vue/Nuxt.js)

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex, nuxt.js

I run a chat application with Firebase Firestore and it works all super well, however I'm running into the following issue:

For paginating my conversations & chats I use **query cursors** for my listeners. I save these query cursors into my state (vuex) so I can access them later when needed. That works and I can paginate my chat messages and conversations.

I create query cursors like so:

```
const query = await ref.get()
const cursor = query.docs[query.docs.length - 1]
commit('SET_CONVERSATIONS_QUERY_CURSOR', cursor)
```

And later use them in the next query like so:

```
.startAfter(state.conversations.queryCursor)
```

Everything actually works perfect.

My issue now is that that cursor saved in my state seem to be updated regularly (...why Firebase?) & especially directly. This gives me the following error messages when using vuex strict-mode (-> not allowed to access the state directly):

> app.js:506 Error: [vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside
>   mutation handlers.

Now I of course want to use strict mode to avoid mutation state directly, but I can't due to the query cursors in my state.

I tried to clone the cursor before saving in to the store, but shallow clones did no good and deep clones did not work because of `Converting circular structure to JSON`.

So...

- Is there a recommended way on how to store query cursors for later use?
- Are there options to just store the id of a document and later "recreate" a query cursor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent javascript object from getting modified by using `Object.freeze(obj)`.

So in your case it should be `const cursor = Object.freeze(query.docs[query.docs.length - 1])`

Comment: This is helpful! Thanks.